# .NET RabbitMQ send and receive

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, rabbitmq

I am developing two apps in .NET connected between RabbitMQ. I have tried with the rabbitmq web's example, but is not working.

I have another android app and it receives ok the messages from a .NET app with RabbitMQ, but between two .NET apps is not working.

I have two differents projects, one to send and another to receive.

Send.cs

```
string nombreCola = "Test";
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.Uri = "amqp://user:pass@ip:5672/NameVirtualHost";
        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            channel.QueueDeclare(queue: nombreCola,
                                 durable: false,
                                 exclusive: false,
                                 autoDelete: false,
                                 arguments: null);

            string message = mensaje;
            var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

            channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "",
                                 routingKey: nombreCola,
                                 basicProperties: null,
                                 body: body);
            Console.WriteLine(" [x] Sent {0}", message);
        }
```

Receive.cs

```
string nombreCola = "Test";
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.Uri = "amqp://user:ip:5672/NameVirtualHost";
        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            channel.QueueDeclare(queue: nombreCola,
                                 durable: false,
                                 exclusive: false,
                                 autoDelete: false,
                                 arguments: null);

            var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
            consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
            {
                var body = ea.Body;
                var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0}", message);
                label1.Text = message;
            };
            channel.BasicConsume(queue: nombreCola,
                                 noAck: true,
                                 consumer: consumer);

            Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: Looks like your receiver is a console application. I think that event consumer is not multi threaded. Try consume in the separate thread because Console.Readline() locks main thread.